# multi screen support application in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I have developed one application with tab bar at bottom and 
with multiple activity in every tab. Now I am facing screen resolution problem. I want to make my application comfortable with every resolution. I have some activity with few text boxes and buttons at particular position. How can I create layout file that fit every screen properly? If anyone can provide me example of xml file it would be very helping.
I have gone through http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html link but can't get any help.

Comment: We can't tell you much more than what you've read already. Do you have a particular problem on which we can focus?

Comment: How about you paste the XML that you are using and we can make suggestions or point out bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

In xml you can find LinearLayout and it has id and 
for layout width which will be fill_parent or wrap_content where fill_parent will allowing device to use fullwidth and wrap_content will use fixed width of content
set layout attributes to

```
layout_width:FILL_PARENT
layout_height:WRAP_CONTENT
```

hope this works for you..